# Creating a custom 2 way encryption class

Tags: encryption, substitution-cipher

I am trying to make a simple 2 way encryption function that currently uses a substitute cipher for the encryption and an inverse substitution for the decryption.

I want to move away from this substitution algorithm, so my question is as follows:

What things do I need to look out for when creating a custom encrypt/decrypt algorithm?

Link to question with code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114881/custom-algorithm-for-hashing-and-un-hashing-password)

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: **cross-posted** at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114881/custom-algorithm-for-hashing-and-un-hashing-password) – please do not cross-post your question(s) as this is frowned upon at SE. Besides that, the question *`What things do I need to look out for when creating a custom encrypt/decrypt algorithm?`* is too broad; which provides another reason to put this question on hold. For details, I’ld like to invite you to please check out [our help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In general, creating your own "encryption/decryption" algorithm is a BAD IDEA.

The algorithm you've chosen would be subject to an attack known as Frequency Analysis. There are 26! (2^88) keys, which is generally reasonable (would be hard to brute force). But if you were to analyse the cryptotext, you'd quickly see that "B" is much more common than a random string.

This really wouldn't be too hard to break.

In reality, there are a large array of different cryptanalysis attack vectors, some of which are quite nuanced. Try just reading up on cryptanalysis of Enigma to see just how inventive attacks can be.

If you want this to be truly secure, I'd recommend using a well-known implementation of a well-known encryption algorithm (such as AES).